# Exclude specific rows from table in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `Blacklist` and table named `Order`.

Both have `CustomerId` column.

Stored Procedure `ExecOrder` manipulates `Order` table.

My goal is to exclude Orders that have Blacklisted CustomerId (meaning : Order's CustomerId is in Blacklist table).

I edited `ExecOrder` SP like this:

```
    DECLARE @Temp TABLE
    (
        CustomerId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    );
    INSERT INTO @Temp
        SELECT RightSide
        FROM Blacklist
        WHERE LeftSide = @CustomerId;

    BEGIN
            DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
            FOR SELECT OrderId
                FROM dbo.[Order] ord
                LEFT OUTER JOIN @Temp t ON t.CustomerId <> ord.CustomerId AND ord.CustomerId <> @CustomerId
                WHERE AssetId = @BaseAsset
                      AND CurrencyId = @QuoteAsset
                      AND OrderTypeId <> @OrderType
                      AND [QuotePrice] <= @QuotePrice
                      AND OrderStatusId = 10
                      AND Amount > ISNULL(AmountFilled, 0)
                      AND OrderId < @OrderId
                      AND OrderBookId = @OrderBookId
                      AND DeliveryStart = @DeliveryPeriodStart
                      AND DeliveryEnd = @DeliveryPeriodEnd
                      AND @MinAmount <= Amount - ISNULL(AmountFilled, 0) 
                ORDER BY OrderDate;

    END;
```

@Temp table returns correct list of CustomerIds.
Problem is that blacklisted orders are not excluded.

Comment: Why don't you remove the temp table, and simply add `where not exists (select * from blacklist where LeftSide=@CustomerID)`. I think you will get a better answer if you post more of your code because as it stands your customerid isn't used to restrict orders.

Comment: You are still not doing anything with your temp table, other than the join. You are not doing anything different depending on whether you match a row or not. Please provide some more information - at least schema of your BlackList and Order table and hopefully some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @Temp table is holding blacklisted customers.

```sql
-- contains blacklisted customer
INSERT INTO @Temp
        SELECT RightSide
        FROM Blacklist
        WHERE LeftSide = @CustomerId;
```

Now, you need to select orders of customers not existing in @Temp table.

```sql
-- You need to select orders, where customerId not exists in @Temp table
SELECT OrderId
                FROM dbo.[Order] ord
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from @Temp WHERE customerId = ord.CustomerId) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should connect with blacklist and take only where connected blacklist not existst:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Temp t ON t.CustomerId <> ord.CustomerId AND ord.CustomerId <> @CustomerId
```

Change to:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Temp t ON t.CustomerId = ord.CustomerId OR ord.CustomerId = @CustomerId
```

Next you should check if it is empty:

```
WHERE ... AND t.CustomerId IS NULL
```